# Django form empty numeric field clean validation

Tags: django, forms, validation

Im trying to validate in a django form if the user entered a numeric value on a field called "usd_value" using the clean method like this :

**Form.py**

```
class CostItemsForm(ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CostItemsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = CostItems
        fields = [
                    'group',
                    'description', 
                    'usd_value', 
                    'rer',
                    'pesos_value', 
                    'supplier', 
                    'position',
                    'observations',
                    'validity_date',
                ]

    def clean_usd_value(self):

        if self.cleaned_data.get('usd_value'):
            try:
                return int(self.cleaned_data['usd_value'].strip())
            except ValueError:
                raise ValidationError("usd_value must be numeric")
        return 0
```

But is not working, i mean, if i leave the field empty or enter a text value there, alert doesn't activate at all and i got error (obviously) if i try to save the form. Any help ??

Here's my **views.py**

```
class CostItemInsert(View):
    template_name='cost_control_app/home.html'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.has_perm('cost_control_app.add_costitems'):
            form_insert = CostItemsForm(request.POST)
            if form_insert.is_valid():
                form_save = form_insert.save(commit = False)
                form_save.save(force_insert = True) 
                messages.success(request, "cost item created")
                #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('cost_control_app:cost_item'))   
            else:
                messages.error(request, "couldn't save the record")
                return render(request, self.template_name,{
                                                            "form_cost_item":form_insert,
                                                          })
        else:
            messages.error(request, "you have no perrmissions to this action")

        form_cost_item = CostItemsForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name,{
                                    "form_cost_item":form_cost_item,
                                })
```

Comment: How is the `usd` field defined in your model?

Comment: Like this : 
usd_value = models.IntegerField(verbose_name ='USD price')

Comment: I'm not sure about the constructor in your model form instance. I don't think you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function name is wrong. Your field name is `usd_value` but your function is `clean_usd`. Change it to `clean_usd_value` and it should work.

Check [Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) section `The clean_<fieldname>()`.

**Edit**

Also your return value for your clean method is wrong. Check the [django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) example, you need to return the cleaned_data not 0:

```
def clean_usd_value(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data.get('usd_value'):
    try:
        int(cleaned_data)
    except ValueError:
        raise ValidationError("usd_value must be numeric")

    return cleaned_data
```

But on a second throught, you might not even need the `clean_usd_value` method at all, django form field should have the default validation for you. Remove entirely the `clean_usd_value` method and see if it works.

Comment: Updated the function name but still not working, if i leave usd_value field empty there's no alert and i got the form.save() error

Comment: I updated my question adding the views,py code, could you please check ?

Comment: I edited my answer. I don't think you ever need what you have, because django should already covered the validation for `IntegerField`. I was just trying to correct you on how to write `clean_foo` method.

Comment: Correct, but it only covers numeric validation, not if the fileld is empty so that's why i was trying to create a function to do so.

Comment: But you don't have `null=True` in your model field definition, a `ModelForm` should create validation on that as well. How come it will be null? Have you tried it?

Comment: Because it can't be null, if i set [null=false] the form will validate it on his own ?

Comment: No, `null=True` mean "allow field to be null". You don't have it so it can't be null. You form should validate that automatically, or it doesn't? If it doesn't, try to remove your `clean_usd_value` method all together and try again.

Comment: Jeje, no, i know null=true means that, but this field can't be null, that's why i haven't set that property at all....if i remove the clean_usd_value it doesn't validate either, just takes me to the else of the "form_insert.isvalid()" conditional...in other words, still not working.

Comment: Nah, it's working. because your form did validate and failed the validation. If you print `form_insert.errors` in the `else` branch, it would tell you that the form contains validation fails. You need to read the django doc again on how to handle form and form validation errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need custom validation for this. In fact, I think the builtin validation for `django.forms.FloatField` is going to be better than what you have.

Based on your error, I'm assuming that the form isn't using a `FloatField` for `usd_value`, and that's a bit odd. Make sure that your `CostItems` model has `usd_value` defined as a `django.db.models.FloatField` like below.

```
from django.db import models

class CostItems(models.Model):
    usd_value = models.FloatField()
    # other stuff
```

Once you do this, your `CostItemsForm` should automatically use `django.forms.FloatField` for `usd_value`. If it doesn't, you can always define this field explicitly.

```
from django import forms

class CostItemsForm(ModelForm):

    usd_value = forms.FloatField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CostItems
        fields = [
            'group',
            'description', 
            'usd_value', 
            'rer',
            'pesos_value', 
            'supplier', 
            'position',
            'observations',
            'validity_date',
        ]
```

If neither of these suggestions is helpful, please post your `CostItems` model.